# How to define two functions with the same name and parameters, if one of them has a reference?

Tags: c++, reference

I have code:

```
int SomeClass::sum(int x)
{
    return x+=x;
}

int SomeClass::sum(int & x)
{
    return x+=x;
}
```

....

```
int num = 0;
int result = sum(num);
```

that not work. How I can use both functions and indicate which of them I want to use when I сall them?

Comment: Does your design make sense? In the first overload there are no side effects to the function...

Comment: If you call sum with a constant:  sum(123) the compiler knows it's not a reference.  Otherwise, you are plum out of luck.

Comment: @David Rodríguez - dribeas: It,s just example

Answer (score 2):

You can provide two different overloads taking `int&` and `const int&`, which might somehow meet your needs...

But the whole code is a bit strange... in the function that takes the argument by value you are *modifying* it (`+=`), when it probably makes sense to only *read* it `return x+x;`. In the overload that takes the reference, you are both *modifying* the argument and *returning* the new value. That is a bit strange.

Other than that, `sum` is a horrible name for a function that multiplies by 2.

Answer (score 1):

You can not have such functions in `C++`. They will have to be named differently for instance `sumByCopy` and `sumByRef`. How would you expect the compiler to decide which one are you referring to at each point?

Comment: Sure we can have such functions, but we just cannot call them directly due to ambiguity, therefore, it does not make sense to provide them in this way, but not because we cannot have such functions together in C++.

Comment: @tacp: ... and you can even call them! `const int i = 10; sum(i);`, or `int i = 10; static_cast<int (*)(int)>(f)(i); static_cast<int(*)(int&)>(f)(i);`...

Answer (score 0):

You can overload in this way, it will compile OK if you do not call any of them directly. However, it will cause ambiguity when you call `sum(num)`. Therefore, it is no sense to provide those overloads of a function since we cannot directly call none of them. This kind of overloads is useless and violates good practice.