# Multiple functions with the same name but their parameters are either constant or received by value or by reference

Tags: c++, constants, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value, pass-by-const-reference

The title is a bit lengthy, but it's best explained by an example:

Suppose we have the following functions in C++:

```cpp
void SomeFunction(int num) { //1

}

void SomeFunction(int& num) { //2

}

void SomeFunction(const int& num) { //3

}

void SomeFunction(const int num) { //4

}
```

All of these are called the same way:

```
SomeFunction(5);
```

or

```
int x = 5;
SomeFunction(x);
```

When I tried to compile the code, it rightfully says `more than one instance of overloaded function "SomeFunction" matches the argument`

My question is: Is there a way to tell the compiler which function I meant to call?

I asked my lecturer if it was possible, and she tried something along

```
SomeFunction< /*some text which I don't remember*/ >(x);
```

But it didn't work and she asked me to find out and tell her.

I also encounter this post:
[How to define two functions with the same name and parameters, if one of them has a reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15905749/how-to-define-two-functions-with-the-same-name-and-parameters-if-one-of-them-ha)
And it seems that 1 and 2 can't be written together, but what about 3 and 4? Can either one of those be called specifically?

Comment: I would question why these overloads exists in the first place. From the callers perspective there is no difference between `SomeFunction(int num)`, `SomeFunction(const int num)` and I believe also `SomeFunction(const int& num)`.

Comment: Overload 3 and 4 are kind of useless.

Comment: It seems your lecturer does not know how template works (nor what are template). It's not something we can add any old way :D Those are functions here and not function templates, so specifying a template type in the call cannot compile obviously.

Comment: Overloads 1 and 4 are not really overloads but violation of ODR as top level const is ignored in function signature.

Comment: @churill `SomeFunction(int num)` and `SomeFunction(const int num)` are *the same* function. If there are two definitions, the program is ill-formed anyway

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yeah I know some of those shouldn't _logically_ be used together (they won't change the parameter called anyway). Still, I was curious if that's technically possible. Function 2 and either one of the others is the only likely scenario, rather than all 4 of them together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 and 4 have the same signature, so you'll need to drop one of those.

The other functions cannot be called directly, but you could add a template function that allows you to specify the desired parameter type:

```
template<class Arg>
void Call(void f(Arg), Arg arg)
{
    f(arg);
}

// Driver Program to test above functions
int main()
{
    int i;
    Call<int>(SomeFunction, 1);
    Call<int&>(SomeFunction, i);
    Call<const int&>(SomeFunction, 1);
}
```

Alternatively you could use a function pointer to choose the signature.

```
int i;
static_cast<void(*)(int)>(&SomeFunction)(1);
static_cast<void(*)(int&)>(&SomeFunction)(i);
static_cast<void(*)(const int&)>(&SomeFunction)(1);
```

It would be preferrable to avoid this scenario though and only define overloads for either references or the signature `void SomeFunction(int)`.

---

Note:

```
SomeFunction<some text which I don't remember>(x);
```

only works for template functions and `SomeFunction` is not a template function, so this is not an option here.

Comment: Thanks. To expend on your answer, if any of those functions were to return a value, the template would look something like this: 

`template<class Arg, class returnType>
returnType Call(returnType f(Arg), Arg arg)
{return f(arg);}`

Calling the function: `int var = Call<int, int>(SomeFunction, 1);`
And using the function pointer:`int var=static_cast<int(*)(int)>(SomeFunction)(1);`

Answer (score 0):

You can HACK it, and I mean it - it's not a good solution to your problem, by static casting your function explicitly:

```
    static_cast<void(*)(int)>(SomeFunction)(i);
    static_cast<void(*)(int&)>(SomeFunction)(i);
    static_cast<void(*)(const int&)>(SomeFunction)(i);
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/roeYM3Gos)
It will work for first 3 overloads. 4th one is equivalent to 1st: quote from the standard [over.load]:

> Parameter declarations that differ only in the presence or absence of const and/or volatile are
> equivalent. That is, the const and volatile type-specifiers for each parameter type are ignored when
> determining which function is being declared, defined, or called

and there is an example:

```
int f (int);
int f (const int); // redeclaration of f(int)
```

Also note that you cannot call 2nd overload with rvalue (temporary).

Comment: _"Also note that you cannot call 2nd overload with rvalue (temporary)."_
Why not? I tried the following and it worked for me: `int var = static_cast<int(*)(int&)>(SomeFunction)(i);`

Comment: Because `i` is lvalue.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I see this working the way your lecturer tried is if `SomeFunction` is a template and these four overloads are specializations.

```
template<typename T>
void SomeFunction(T num);

template<>
void SomeFunction<int>(int num) {}

template<>
void SomeFunction<int&>(int& num) {}

template<>
void SomeFunction<const int&>(const int& num) {}

template<>
void SomeFunction<const int>(const int num) {}
```

Then you can call it as follows.

```
SomeFunction<int>(x);
SomeFunction<int&>(x);
SomeFunction<const int&>(x);
SomeFunction<const int>(x);
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/xxhTzq7jd)

However, this is incredibly stupid in this context. There are a lot of things wrong with the original overloads.

In the 4th one, the `const` is completely useless from the caller's perspective, because you can call it the same way you can call the 1st, and the argument is a copy anyway. The `const` only makes it so the argument is constant *inside* the function. Moreover, the 1st and 4th overloads cannot both be defined at the same time: the `const` is actually ignored in the prototype and it leads to a redefinition.

The 3rd overload is also useless because a `const int&` argument provides no benefit over a `int` argument. In fact, the compiler probably optimizes that away. The only difference is in the scenario I describe at the end. Of course, if the argument type is more complex (not just `int` or some other fundamental type), it often makes sense.

The 2nd overload is the only one that can modify the variable you pass as argument. However, if the 1st (or 4th, since it's really the same) overload is present as well, you cannot call the 2nd directly because the call would be ambiguous. You could still call the 1st with an *rvalue* (basically a literal or an expression like `std::move(x)`).

If the 2nd and 3rd overloads are the only ones present, then there is no ambiguity and you can call the 2nd with non-const lvalues and the 3rd with const lvalues or rvalues.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/5P37G7hYd)

Comment: _"Of course, if the argument type is more complex (not just int or some other fundamental type), it often makes sense."_ You're correct I used `int` for simplicity's sake and that example is without a doubt 'incredibly stupid' as you put it. I would use (some of) those functions only for more complex scenarios, If at all. I also expended on that in my reply to someone on the question post itself.